# How to get only date from "Date" field in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def generate_leave(self, cr, uid,ids, fields, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    month_split = self.browse( cr, uid,ids)
    print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DATEE",month_split.name 
    dt =  datetime.strptime(month_split.name, "%Y-%m-%d")
    # date= dt.strftime(month_split.name[],'%Y-%m-%d')
    # print "\n\n\n\n\n DAT",date
    year = dt.year
    print "\n\n\n\n YER",year
    month = dt.month
    print "\n\n\n MNTH",month
    currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    print "\n\n\n\n\n CURR MNTH",currentMonth
    date = dt.date
    print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DATTE",date
    date = datetime.now().day
    print "\n\n\n\n\n\n DATEE",date
```

This is my code. I am able to get current date separately. But in my scenario user will input a date and I want to take only the "Date" from that input, I don't want month and year.

Comment: add your input and desired output

Comment: you can format the input date from user as datetime format, then do the same logic as showing in your code `dt.date` to get the date.

Comment: Let me guess: you want to do something like `date = dt.day`?

Comment: yes wanderlust.

Comment: Tiny,  if am changing my user input field to date time then i want to change my whole logic to get day,month and year , coz i want to format those m:h:s from datetime.